# Summarizing a collection of correlation coefficients?

Tags: r, correlation

Let me ask my question by using a toy example in R:

```
library(faux)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

#simulate data
cor_matrix <- frame_matrix(
  ~A,   ~B,   ~I,   ~II,  ~III,
   1,    0,    0.5, -0.4,  0.6,   
   0,    1,    0.2,  0.1,  0,
   0.5,  0.2,  1,    0,    0,
  -0.4,  0.1,  0,    1,    0,
   0.6,  0,    0,    0,    1
)
rownames(cor_matrix) <- c("A", "B", "I", "II", "III")

sim <- rnorm_multi(
  n = 50,
  vars = 5,
  varnames = c("A", "B", "I", "II", "III"),
  mu = 0,
  sd = 1,
  r = cor_matrix,
  empirical = TRUE
)

sim_longer <- sim %>% pivot_longer(I:III, names_to = "dep_var", values_to = "dep_values")

#plot relationship between independent and dependent values
ggplot(sim_longer, aes(A, dep_values)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  facet_wrap(~dep_var, ncol = 3)

ggplot(sim_longer, aes(B, dep_values)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  facet_wrap(~dep_var, ncol = 3)

#show correlations coefficients
cor(sim)[1:2, 3:5] %>% View
```

The data I simulated consists of two independent variables (A, B) and three dependent variables (I, II, III). As visualized in the following plots A is strongly (but not always positively) correlated with all of the dependent variables, whereas B is only weakly correlated with the dependent variables.

[image: Var A]
[image: Var B]

The correlation coefficients are as follows

[image: coefs]

Here is my question:

*Is there a single metric that would allow me to rank the independent variables by how strongly each correlates with the dependent variables **overall**.*

One approach could be to sum up the absolute correlation coefficients or use their product. E.g.

```
abs_coefs <- cor(sim)[1:2, 3:5] %>% abs
rowSums(abs_coefs)
apply(abs_coefs, 1, prod)
```

```
Sum:
A   B 
1.5 0.3
```

```
Product:
           A            B 
1.200000e-01 3.253962e-18
```

I am (as I'm sure you have guessed by now) not a statistician. So my intuition is that likely

- a) this way of summarizing correlations is problematic (please tell me why)
- b) there is a better and statistically sound way to summarize and compare multiple correlation coefficients
- c) there is an entirely different and much simpler approach to this problem

Searching the web and CrossValidated hasn't led me to an answer. But somehow I get the feeling that I am not asking the right question in the first place.

Thank you very much for your help!

EDIT:
To put this into context here is the use case, which led me to this question. I am working with RNA-sequencing data and have called modules of co-regulated genes using [WGCNA](https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/) that represent different biological processes (an example could be genes that are upregulated together in cell division). I also have a list of candidate genes that could be potential drivers of these modules. For each of these I looked at how much its expression correlates with the overall expression of each module. In WGCNA terminology this is called the ['module membership'](https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/Tutorials/FemaleLiver-03-relateModsToExt.pdf). I find that the expression of some of these candidate driver genes correlates with the expression of multiple modules (positvely or negatively), whereas others are only correlated with a single module and many of them are not correlated to the expression of any of the modules. What I would like to do is to prioritize candidate driver genes for further experimental study that potentially have a broad biological influence (meaning they correlate with multiple modules positively or negatively). Just to make that clear, I fully understand that correlation is not causation. I just need a good metric to rank the list of candidate driver genes in order to then test a manageable number of targets further.

EDIT2:
Following the suggestion from the comments I calculated the bootstrap rank confidence intervals for my real world data as follows:

- Create 100,000 bootstrap samples by drawing with replacement from my original 174 samples
- for each bootstrap sample: correlate each candidate driver gene with the expression of each module, sum up the absolute correlation coefficients per gene and rank the genes according to the summed coefficients (rank 1 has the highest summed coefficients in my case)
- Calculate the 95% bootstrap confidence intervals for each gene

Here is what the results look like

[image: Bootstrap rank confidence intervals]

As described above I would like to use this as a guide to prioritize genes for further study, based on how strong they correlate overall with the expression of the different gene co-expression modules. For example gene 23, 17, 43, 5 seem to be good candidates for further study if I interpret the data correctly.

Comment: You seem to conflate a collection of ordinary (univariate) coefficients with "multiple correlation coefficients." The two can be (completely) different.  When your interest lies in understanding the collective relationship between several independent variables and a dependent variable, then studying the univariate regressions is limited and can be misleading.  Could you therefore clarify what it is you really want to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you for helping me to clarify the question and pointing out that 'multiple correlation coefficients' is a term with it's own meaning. I changed the title accordingly. I also added the real-world problem that led me to the question at the end of the post. I hope this better explains what I would like to achieve. Let me know if can make anything clearer stil.

Comment: If it is informative to look at correlation coefficients in a simple bivariate fashion, use the bootstrap to compute confidence intervals for the ranks of the absolute values of the correlations in the correlation matrix.  This fully exposes the difficulty of the task, and the ability of the data to do what you hope they do.  See the Challenges of HIgh DImensional Data Analysis chapter in [BBR](https://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf).  This is more appropriate when there are many more correlations being examined.

Comment: @FrankHarrell thank you very much for your suggestion and also for providing a great and free resource. I read through the chapter and have added the bootstrap rank confidence intervals for the actual data to my original post. Is this what you meant?

Comment: It looks pretty good.  I'm not familiar with summing absolute values of correlation coefficients and am not certain how to interpret that.